# Comparing text files character-by-character in C

Tags: c, io, char

I'm writing a small program which does as follows:
When executed, takes as arguments, two text files.
Compares each text file character by character, displaying to the user whether each comparison was successful or not.
When two characters (in the same position) are not the same, this is told to the user, and the program finishes.
If the two text files are the same entirely, this is also told the user, and the program ends.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // define main procedure, taking an command line argument
{
    int ch, ch2; // index for current character
    FILE *fp; // pointer to file
    FILE *fp2;
    unsigned long count = 0;

if (argc != 3) //
{
    printf("Usage: %s filename \n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) // check for 'cannot open' error in first file
{
    printf("Can't open %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else if ((fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL) // check for 'cannot open' error in second file
{
        printf("Can't open %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while ((ch = getc(fp) != EOF) || (ch2 = getc(fp2) != EOF)) // while both files still have characters remaining
{
    printf("\n %d %d \n", ch, ch2); // print both characters (debugging purposes)
    if (ch == ch2) // if two characters are same at current position
    {
        printf("FILES ARE SAME AT POSITION %d", count); // report to user
        count++; // increase count
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FILES ARE NOT NOT NOT SAME AT POSITION %d", count); // report that files are not same at current position
        fclose(fp); // close files
        fclose(fp2);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // exit
    }
}

fclose(fp);
fclose(fp2);
printf("FILES ARE THE SAME THROUGHOUT!");

return 0;
```

However, the program display random characters not in the file when comparing, causing infinite loops and false execution.

Am my file pointers incorrect, or have I messed up a data type somewhere causing this?

Comment: You need to run your program in a debugger and inspect the variables at various points...

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but you might want to fix your while like this.

`while (((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) && ((ch2 = getc(fp2)) != EOF))`

Comment: I'm pretty sure your while conditions have to be connected with &&, otherwise it'll read both files as long as one has not reached eof yet.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht I'm fairly sure that is the intention... You have to read beyond the testing condition of the `while` loop to see why ;)

Comment: but that will result in crap being printed.

Answer (score 3):

First You should change your while loop from

```
while ((ch = getc(fp) != EOF) || (ch2 = getc(fp2) != EOF))
```

to

```
while (((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) || ((ch2 = getc(fp2)) != EOF))
```

As `!=` has higher precedence than `=`, your while loop has a problem always

Answer (score 1):

Consider the position of the parens in this code:

```
if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
```

Now take a close look at, comparing the position of the parens in this code:

```
while ((ch = getc(fp) != EOF) || (ch2 = getc(fp2) != EOF))
```

Do you notice any inconsistency? Perhaps you meant to write this:

```
while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF || (ch2 = getc(fp2)) != EOF)
```

There is another problem with your program. In `printf("FILES ARE SAME AT POSITION %d", count);` you tell `printf` to print an `int` denoted by `count`, but `count` is not an `int`... You should use `%lu` for `unsigned long` values.